# How do I add verticle space on sm:flex-col on mobile devices in tailwindCSS

Tags: tailwind-css

How do I add space between two divs on mobile devices, the space is well added on tablets and above but on mobile, it is failing.

Here is the code I have and images on mobile, tablet, and laptop.

```html
   <FormSection
            title="Basic Details"
            description="Fill in the basic details of your business."
        >

            <div
                class="md:flex justify-between space-between lg:flex-row lg:space-y-0 sm:space-x-0 sm:flex-col sm:space-y-5 lg:space-x-10 align-content-center align-middle">

                <div class="w-full">
                    <InputText
                        id="name"
                        label="Business Name"
                        description="Legally registered name."
                        v-model="form.name"
                        required
                    />
                </div>

                <div class="w-full">
                    <InputText
                        id="registration_number"
                        label="Registration Number"
                        description="Legal registration number."
                        v-model="form.registration_number"
                    />
                </div>

            </div>

   </FormSection>
```

On Laptop: `has space between Name and Reg No fields`
[image]

On Tablet: `has space between Name and Reg No fields`
[image]

On Mobile: `There is NO space between Name and Reg No fields`
[image]

How do I add that verticle space on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive `sm:space-y-5` works only for screen size greater than 640px. The prefix `sm:` is a breakpoint which tells tailwind to use the following directive only on screen sizes greater than 640px (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens). I assume the screen size of your mobile device is smaller than 640px and therefore the directive `space-y-5` is not applied.

To apply the directive `space-y-5` to also smaller screen sizes change the part `sm:space-y-5` to `space-y-5`, so this would be applied to every screen size (also to the smaller ones). The directive `lg:space-y-0` overrides then the `space-y-5` directive for screen sizes greater than 1024px.